# Create event participate using OOP API in CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity

There are 2 different sites in Drupal. In one of them there is CiviCRM is installed. Now I want to create event participate from first site which will use CiviCRM of second site. I have successfully get the list of events from second site to first site using:

```
$api = new civicrm_api3 (array ('server' => 'http://localhost/civicrm', 'api_key'=>'xxx', 'key'=>'xxx'));

if ($api->Event->Get()) {
    print_r($api);
} else {
    echo $api->errorMsg();
}
```

Now I want to create event participate using OOP API in CiviCRM. So I have create code something like that:

```
$params = array(
        'contact_id'    => 1,
        'event_id'      => 2,
        'status_id'     => 1,
        'role_id'       => 1,
        'register_date' => '2007-07-21',
        'source'        => 'Online Event Registration: API Testing',
        'event_level'   => 'Tenor'
);

if ($api->Participate->Create($params)) {
    print_r($api);
} else {
    echo $api->errorMsg();
}
```

But in response I'm getting:
**API (Participate, create) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)**

So is it still in development? any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo. Please try `$api->Participant->Create($params))` and let us know the result.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/examples/Participant/Create.php

Comment: Yup I found that too 2 days ago. But anyway thanks @Nicholai